# Apereo CAS 6.0.x Pass the login form field to the resolved attributes

Tags: field, cas, principal

I need to add a field to the CAS 6.0.X login screen (language selector) that is not used to authenticate users but I need it after logging in.
How can I do to pass this field added to the form to the data that is passed to the client application in the "principal" object.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have achieved what I needed. We have overwritten the jdbc support module to add checks and there I have put the following code that helps me to retrieve parameters of the request.

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) 
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
String[] fields = fieldsToPrincipal.split(",");
for(String field : fields2Principal) 
{
    dbFields.put( field.trim() , request.getParameter( field.trim() ) );
}
```

fieldsToPrincipal It is a string of form field names that I want to send the applications through the "principal" map attributes.

Now in the properties files I have 2 properties in which I report the names of the fields. The default property that tells you which fields will be retrieved for the principal and my custom property where I indicate which fields will come from the form

cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].principalAttributeList:USERID, USERNAME, LANGUAGE_SELECTED
cas.custom.properties.jdbc.loginfields.to.principal=LANGUAGE_SELECTED